# Elasticsearch fielddata unsupported while index mapping

Tags: python, elasticsearch, schema, elasticsearch-indices

I'm trying to create an index in Elasticsearch through Python. I have a local instance of ES deployed and queries run fine. However, I have a schema. Here it is:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "payment":{
      "properties":{
        "timestamp":{"type":"date"},
        "base_amount":{"type":"integer"},
        "derived_id":{"type":"keyword", "fielddata": true},
        "attempts":{"type":"integer"},
        "status":{"type":"text","fielddata":true},
        "error_code":{"type":"text","fielddata":true}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to create this index

```
import json

import requests

schema = {
    "mappings": {
        "payment": {
            "properties": {
                "timestamp": {"type": "date"},
                "base_amount": {"type": "integer"},
                "derived_key": {"type": "keyword", "fielddata": True},
                "attempts": {"type": "integer"},
                "status": {"type": "text", "fielddata": True},
                "error_code": {"type": "text", "fielddata": True}
            }
        }
    }
}

index = 'http://localhost:9200/payment_index_2016_08_21'
r = requests.put(index, data=json.dumps(schema))

print r.content
```

The error I get is

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping
>   definition for [derived_key] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata :
>   true]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse
>   mapping [payment]: Mapping definition for [derived_key] has
>   unsupported parameters:  [fielddata :
>   true]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping
>   definition for [derived_key] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata :
>   true]"}},"status":400}

I don't understand why the `fielddata = true` is causing an issue, since I see it's allowed here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html. Any clue what the issue behind this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to enable `fielddata` on keyword fields. you can do aggregations on keyword fields.

Comment: Yup it works. So what you mean is that on keywords, you can perform aggregation by default and we don't need to enable that by fielddata = true (since it's already enabled) and the purpose of fielddata is to perform aggreations, correct?

Comment: Yes are are correct. some tasks like `aggregations`, `sorting`, ... need different requirements than `search` and text fields are mean to be searched in by default an other fields can be aggregated/sorted on by default. So if you need sorting/aggregation/... on text fields you should enable fielddata for them which could be memory expensive!

Comment: Done. Just changed it to text instead of keyword and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Good. You can take a look at `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html` for more detailed information about fielddata.